# JQGrid: Issue with Search JQGrid data through NavGrid Button

Tags: jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

I have to set JQGrid property loadonce : true for searching JQGrid data.
For loadonce: false searching is not possible.

My grid containg multiple pages. But while setting loadonce : true , my pagination is not working. its showing disabled.

```
 //Search  
   {
     searchOnEnter: true,
     closeOnEscape: true,
     reloadAfterSearch: true
    },
```

How can I make pagination work along with search operation.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `loadonce: true` then the server should return **all data** instead of returning one page. jqGrid will save locally all the data in internal `data` and `_index` parameter and it will display only the first page of data. The paging will be enabled and it will be implemented locally like sorting and filtering/searching.